# How to sort vector< pair< int , pair<int , pair<string , pair<int , int > > > > >?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I am learning to use STL's sort function by putting it to use to some complex vector of pairs.

I have the following vector:

```
vector< pair< int , pair< int , pair< string , pair< int , int > > > > >
```

I need to first sort the elements based on the first integer in the pair, and if it turns out that there are 2 elements with the identical values, then I need to sort them on the basis of the integer present in the inner pair.

if I represent the above type as:

```
vector< pair< I , pair< G , pair< S , pair< T , T > > > > >
```

first I need to sort them according to I and then according to G. Can this be done efficiently, just using comparators?

Comment: What does your sort code look like?  do you have any code to share?

Comment: I'm getting tired of repeating this in the other answers. [std::pair implements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) lexicographical comparison. All you need to do is call `std::sort`, and it will work out of the box. Behold the power of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`std::sort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) passing a suitable comparison function as `comp`. The [default comparison function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) will compare elements the way that you want them ordered.

Comment: I think the default one will do. [std::pair defines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) several templated lexicographical comparion operators.

Comment: Question: "I want to use `std::sort`, but how do I write that comparator?" Answer: "Call `std::sort` with a suitable comparator".

Comment: The question is how to sort a vector, not how to write a comperator. "Can this be done efficiently, just using comparators?" Well, yes.

Comment: @Joker_vD, the answer is that the standard library will generate a proper `operator<` for our friend here.

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed. Which is great, since I've seen non-total comparators that led to "funny" bugs.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, a custom comparison function seems indeed not to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, the default comparison within `std::pair` will work.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
bool operator<( const pair<T1,T2>& lhs, const pair<T1,T2>& rhs );
```

Apply this rule with one recursion step to see that this is the case:

> If lhs.first < rhs.first, returns true. Otherwise, if
>   rhs.first < lhs.first, returns false. Otherwise, if
>   lhs.second < rhs.second, returns true. Otherwise, returns false.

In C++11, if you need to choose the sorting criterion at runtime, you can use a lambda for comparison.  It should take const references to the type, and return bool.

Here is what it would look like.

```
typedef pair< int , pair< int , pair< string , pair< int , int > > > > MyComplexType;
std::vector<MyComplexType> v;
// fill v

// sort
auto complexLessThan = [](const MyComplexType& left, const MyComplexType& right)  -> bool
{
    // your sorting criterion here           
}

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), complexLessThan);
```

Comment: I need a structure comparator for doing this don't have C++11 with me

Comment: What have you tried so far.  Writing a custom comparison operator is a very common question on SO.